# Eddystone (which beacon is interacting?)

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, eddystone, google-nearby

From multiple beacons placed at a location, how can we know from which beacon the user accessed the URL ? I am using Nearby notification. Minor value of beacon would help ? If yes then how ? Or pls suggest an alternative solution.

Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the same question by this same user: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443725/nearby-notification-minor-value

Comment: I wanted to modify the content of the question and also wanted to added extra tags after posting the question. Cud not do it, so had to post as a new question..

Answer (score 1):

Append your url with a parameter identifying the beacon. E.g. `http://www.myaddress.com?beaconId=123`